# Execute method after process exited unexpectedly in a test scenario?

Tags: c#, mstest

Is there a way to execute a method in C# AFTER an execution process exited unexpectedly?

My current scenario is: a MSTest unit test project and during the execution process (in this case only with Thread.Sleep) of the unit test I stop the debugging process, can I specify a method that must be called?

(In this case maybe an MSTest attribute?) I've already tried: finalizing and implementing IDisposable

Comment: Can you give a concrete example on what you are trying to do?

Comment: `unexpectedly` meaning there is an error?

Comment: @mrtentje And what was wrong with IDisposable?

Comment: @L-Three already given an example in my question...

Comment: @voo IDisposable is never called if the (debugging) process is stopped ...

Comment: Maybe a Visual Studio Extension may be able to extend debugging behavior. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb161718(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop any process manually (i.e. by terminating the debugging process in the IDE, or by killing a process in task manager), you are circumventing the normal running of your code.  Everything is terminated aggressively and none of your `Dispose` or other shutdown methods will fire: all code execution is stopped.

Note that if you *detach* from the process instead, your code will continue to run, but your process won't be asked to stop.  (Also, for reference: if you "End Task" from the "Applications" tab in task manager, this in fact *requests* the application to stop - which allows shutdown code to fire, but doesn't guarantee that the application will shut down in a timely manner.)

In short: if you stop a debugging process, no code will execute by definition.  I suspect you need to look at an alternate approach: there is presumably a reason that you want your method to be called, and there is probably a different solution that you could try.

Answer (score 0):

If the process you are listen to is not a process that *you* launch (in your case seems like so), I don't see much other options like a simple `Timer` implementation and on every tick controlling if specified process is among processes available in the system memory.